# Google Chart API implementation displaying blank page

Tags: php, html, google-visualization

Attempting to implement a form to insert simple data into a database, then have a google chart display based on the database. Page is currently blank. (I'll worry about the form when the chart displays properly).

I've checked around google for some answers, but the code is basically straight from their tutorial on google charts with a few modifications.

```
<?php
  require_once("apicreds.php");
  $db = new PDO($connectionString, $username , $password);

    if(!$db){echo "Connection Error";}
    if($db){echo "Connected!";}

  $query = "SELECT `country`, `sum(visits)` FROM `trips` GROUP BY 
`country`";
  $result = $db->query($query);
?>
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['country', 'visits'],
        <?php 
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "['".$row['country']."',".$row['sum(visits)']."],";
        }
        ?>
    ]);

    var options = {'title':'Visits To Countries',
                    'is3D':true};

    var chart = new 
google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some of these tags might be messed up, so the full code is here.

https://pastebin.com/31n5KVG2

copy of the current table:

country  visits 
Germany    1 
Canada     2 
UK         1 
UK         1

Ideally, it should output in a 3d pie chart from the table, and update as more data is inserted. That part, I should be able to handle later, but I need help finding out why it won't display at the moment.

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: try debugging what exactly this line gives you and please post it here. I bet there is something wrong that you are getting at this line which is why its failing.

Comment: I tried running your JS code and it perfectly works fine. So, the problem has to be with your PHP and the data that you are getting for each row. Here is the fiddle that shows your JS code is working fine
https://jsfiddle.net/xt9unc0d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to name the sum column using the `as` keyword,
the result will not have a valid key for --> `sum(visits)`

```
$query = "SELECT country, sum(visits) as total_visits FROM trips GROUP BY country";
```

then when loading the data, access the named column...

```
echo "['".$row['country']."',".$row['total_visits']."],";
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!